# Javascript multiple json data combination

Tags: javascript

I have json data like this:

```
{
    variant_57    : {
        variant_id        : 57,
        variant_name    : "Color",
        options                : [
            {option_id:62, option_name:"Blue"},
            {option_id:63, option_name:"White"}
        ]
    },
    variant_71    : {
        variant_id        : 71,
        variant_name    : "Size",
        options                : [
            {option_id:85, option_name:"S"},
            {option_id:86, option_name:"M"},
            {option_id:87, option_name:"L"}
        ]
    },
};
```

The number of options within a variant might change as well as the number of variants. I keep this short so that there wouldn't be too many unnecessary codes. The result that I wanted based on the example above is this.

```
[
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:62,option_name:"Blue"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:85,option_name:"S"}
    ],
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:62,option_name:"Blue"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:86,option_name:"M"}
    ],
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:62,option_name:"Blue"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:87,option_name:"L"}
    ],
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:63,option_name:"White"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:85,option_name:"S"}
    ],
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:63,option_name:"White"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:86,option_name:"M"}
    ],
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:63,option_name:"White"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:87,option_name:"L"}
    ]
];
```

If there was another variant which was named 'type of fabric', the result that I wanted would have been like this.

```
[
    [
        {variant_id:57,variant_name:"Color",option_id:62,option_name:"Blue"},
        {variant_id:71,variant_name:"Size",option_id:85,option_name:"S"},
        {variant_id:101,variant_name:"Fabric",option_id:105,option_name:"Linen"}
    ],
    [...],
    [...],
   .............
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+object+id+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.